# Conflict with Accept */* Header when using default ContentType and @RequestMethod.produces

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, content-type

My Spring application always returns an HTTP 406 - Not acceptable if I try to GET an image from my RestController, if I don't use the correct extension or Accept-Header.

- `curl http://localhost/images/42` -> 406
- `curl http://localhost/images/42.png` -> 200
- `curl http://localhost/images/42 -H 'Accept: image/png'` -> 200

Here is my Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/images/{id}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public void getImage(@PathVariable("id") long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    [...]
}
```

AFAICT spring picks up the default content-type (JSON) if none is requested which is incompatible with the result from the method and thus shows the 406.

```
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .favorParameter(true);
}
```

There is no 406 if I remove the default ContentType, however then my other methods start producing XML/Plain-Text/HTML/stuff (arbitarily), if I omit the Accept-Header/file-extension. (Based on the order of the methods in the controller)

There are some legacy apps out there that don't set the headers and rely on JSON so that is not an option.

---

TLDR: How do I tell Spring that it should only use the default Content-Type if it is compatible with the Controller method that I requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `configureContentNegotiation` method to include a fallback after the default.

[ContentNegotiationConfigurer#defaultContentTypeStrategy(ContentNegotiationStrategy)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer.html#defaultContentTypeStrategy-org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationStrategy-)
[ContentNegotiationStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/accept/ContentNegotiationStrategy.html)

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    final List<MediaType> defaultMediaTypes = ImmutableList.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.ALL);
    // First try the default, if the method produces (@RequestMapping#produces) something else use any.
    configurer.defaultContentTypeStrategy(request -> defaultMediaTypes)
            .favorParameter(true);
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, I didn't see the other method. I wish this would be the default behavior in Spring. I will open a PR on Spring for this improvement, if I have the time.